lsb was removed on noble
masters, lsb package was removed on noble, system always reminder me that "NO LSB moudles are available", is there any impact about this? Btw, can help share the changelog about this? thank you!

The linux standard base was introduced long ago by IBM for s390; I'm betting you're not using a s390 mainframe though; so I wouldn't worry about it.  FYI:  LSB is now rather outdated, being from Qt4 days (removed many years ago) thus isn't that useful even if you're using an IBM mainframe.

FYI:  A quick check, and I do see lsb-release | 12.0-2                | noble          | all meaning the package is available for 24.04 or noble, so I don't understand what you mean by package was removed on noble ?   FYI:  No modules found is what is expected; as 99.9999% of us do not use Linux standard base modules; they're too dated

This is about lsb-core not available anymore on Ubuntu 24.04 noble. Therefore, all lsb_release ever outputs is "No LSB modules are available". OP surely wanted to have the LSB core package show up there, because a 3rd party library depends on it. So the question is really, how does OP get lsb-core to show up in lsb_release in 24.04 noble?

Results of apt policy lsb-release in Ubuntu 24.04:
lsb-release:
  Installed: 12.0-2
  Candidate: 12.0-2

The lsb-release package was not manually installed in my Ubuntu 24.04.
Results of lsb_release in Ubuntu 24.04:
No LSB modules are available.

lsb-release is a tool that is traditionally used to retrieve information about the LSB modules available on a system. Starting with Ubuntu 22.04 the lsb-release project decided to move away from a full LSB implementation in favor of a more lightweight approach. The lsb-release command still exists in Ubuntu 24.04, but it reports that no LSB modules are available.


lsb package was removed on noble

I assume you are refering to the output of the lsb_release command provided by the lsb-release package:
$ apt show lsb-release 
Package: lsb-release
Version: 12.0-2
Priority: important
Section: misc
Source: lsb-release-minimal
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Gioele Barabucci <gioele@svario.it>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 17.4 kB
Homepage: https://gioele.io/lsb-release-minimal
Task: cloud-minimal, minimal, server-minimal
Download-Size: 6564 B
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
Description: Linux Standard Base version reporting utility (minimal implementation)
 The Linux Standard Base (http://www.linuxbase.org/) is a standard
 core system that third-party applications written for Linux can
 depend upon.
 .
 The lsb_release command is a simple tool to help identify the Linux
 distribution being used and its compliance with the Linux Standard Base.
 .
 This package contains a bare-bones implementation that uses the
 information in /etc/os-release instead of relying on LSB packages.

That package actually places an executable shell script at /bin/lsb_release that you can view with e.g.
cat /bin/lsb_release

... and this script sources the file /etc/os-release (symlinked to /usr/lib/os-release) and that's how it gets the OS release information.

system always reminder me that "NO LSB moudles are available", is
there any impact about this?

It had always shown (IIRC) and will always show No LSB modules are available. when it outputs to a TTY  ... Have a look at this part in that shell script:
# Generate minimal standard-conform output (if stdout is a TTY).
[ -t 1 ] && echo "No LSB modules are available." >& 2

... and compare when stdout is a TTY:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

... to when stdout is not a TTY but, instead, a pipe for example:
$ lsb_release -a | tee
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

... and no, there is no impact for that message as you can see.
It's probably a good idea to have a look at the help provided by the script:
$ lsb_release -h
Usage: lsb_release [options]

Options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -v, --version      show LSB modules this system supports
  -i, --id           show distributor ID
  -d, --description  show description of this distribution
  -r, --release      show release number of this distribution
  -c, --codename     show code name of this distribution
  -a, --all          show all of the above information
  -s, --short        show requested information in short format

and specify the option you want.
Those options are parsed and acted upon in a case block:
    case "$1" in
        -h|--help) help ;;
        -v|--version) ;;
        -i|--id) show_id=true ;;
        -d|--description) show_desc=true ;;
        -r|--release) show_release=true ;;
        -c|--codename) show_codename=true ;;
        -a|--all) show_id=true ; show_desc=true ; show_release=true ; show_codename=true ;;
        -s|--short) short_format=true ;;
        *) break  ;;
    esac

... and as seen -v,--version have no action associated with them, so don't be surprised if those options returned nothing.
